# Error ! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
\begin{equation} \label{Latent heat storage}
 E = m[{\int_{t_(i)}^{t_(m)} (c_{ps}dt }+\lambda + {\int_{t_(i)}^{t_(m)} (c_{pl})dt]
\end{equation}
```

The above code shows errors, please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your input; the main one is the `{` before the second `\int`, which is unbalanced.

On the other hand, you don't need to surround an integral with braces.

Here's a fixed version, note also other braces I added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{Latent heat storage}
 E = m\biggl[
   \int_{t_{(i)}}^{t_{(m)}} (c_{ps})\,dt +\lambda
 + \int_{t_{(i)}}^{t_{(m)}} (c_{pl})\,dt
\biggr]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious `{` this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{Latent heat storage}
 E = m[{\int_{t_(i)}^{t_(m)} (c_{ps}dt }+\lambda + \int_{t_(i)}^{t_(m)} (c_{pl})dt]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it was the only thing to fix…

Comment: The `{}` around the first `\int_{t_(i)` are not a TeX errror but probably should not be there.